# How does the Android Studio initiates the Garbage Collector and how does it work?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I am having a hard time trying to find a possible Memory leak.
I've got an Activity which is doing some heavy work in the Background.

After some tasks, the app consumes too much memory. It seems that it does not get cleaned up properly.

**This is the Activity in the default state:**

[image]

If I run the task which the Activity is doing, more and more memory is allocated.

**Activity after some work:**
[image]

At first I thought this must be a Memory Issue, cause the GC can't properly free up the memory. As far as I know, the GC can free the memory, if there are no reference left to the Objects. Is that correct?

**Now comes the part which confuses me:**

If I run the GC from Android Studio, the memory is cleaned up properly and my Activity never gets closed. I just have to use the Android Studio GC when to much memory is allocated.
[image]

This is the one I mean:

[image]

**In general the question is:**

Why can the Android Studio GC clean up the memory properly and why doesn't it work properly with the automatic android GC?

I know this is a pretty general question. I just want to know, if there are different types of garbage collections or something like that.

Also calling `System.gc();` doesn't clean up the memory properly.

**Additional Info:**

Moto G 2nd gen

Android 5.0.2.

Comment: "Sometimes, the Activity or the app closes. I thought it might be caused by memory problems." If the app dies b/c it runs out of memory you will get an Out-of-Memory exception that you can clearly see in Logcat. My hunch is that your app is crashing for another reason. Try looking through logcat to see what the crash reason is.

Comment: The concurrent GC only does partial collection in order to not cause noticeable pauses. Explicit GC such as that triggered by Studio does a full GC sweep. Some reading: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug.html

Comment: @Shmuel There are not Exceptions. Not even warnings.

Comment: @oberflansch What phone is this running on? Android OS Version? Please update the post with as much information as you can provide.

Comment: @Shmuel Thanks for the afford. It's hard to belive that the app gets closed I know. That might have something to do with the android version. But i was generally interested in the GC behaviour. Sorry if I had not made myself clear about that. This closing issue was just some background information.

Comment: @laalto Thanks. That is basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Memory leaks can happen because of several reasons. One common reason are bitmaps which are not recycled correctly. Other seed of memory leaks is keeping the context in objects. For example you launch an async task and pass a context because you need it later. While the async task is running it keeps a reference to the context and so the whole activity is in memory. This is also very frequent with anonymous and inner classes which have a reference to the parent class which usually is a fragment or and activity.

I suggest you to use the library leak canary to spot memory leaks and use the Android tools to track the allocations in order to discover exactly where the memory leak is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mentioned common reasons, how memory leaks occur. Basically is it all befause of remaining references right. But in my case, the the Android Studio GC call is cleaning up everything properly. So if there whould be some strange references, the GC shouldn't be able to clean them up right?

Comment: Not exactly. You may exit one activity but still keep a reference for few seconds. So when you run GC after few seconds it will clean up that memory.
I faced situations where I was going back from several activities and have memory overflow, because maybe a bitmap was being recycled and delayed the GC to free that memory, and so the out of memory happened.

By default the GC does not free memory if it is not necessary (it is not reaching the maximum amount of memory allowed). It can also be your other issue.

Comment: I am glad that I see this thread and it is pretty recent. Have you @oberflansch found the reason why that android studio's GC works better? I am working on the same situation which the application throws me out of memory and the program crashes. One thing I found in my app causing the memory problem was because all the PNG images that I use in the resources are too huge. I am wondering why the android does not GC itself after an activity is closed even all the references in the class are actually closed... the memory just keeps increasing every time when a new activity is created, until it die

Comment: @CaoFelix Well I wouldn't say it is better... The default Android GC tries to cleanup the memory only when it is required. Android Studio GC does a full GC and tried to free up everything. (This takes more time and can cause more lags). My problem at the end was, that the gfx Memory wasn't cleaned up properly (which is not included in the memory tracker). That caused the memory leak. So sometimes the GC doesn't GC cause it thinks is not yet required (for heap).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try to explicitly call `System.gc();` somewhere periodically in your heavy processing code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. I've alrady tried that and it dind't work.

Comment: If there is truly a memory leak then calling System.gc() won't help b/c the memory will still be held on via a reference somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Shmuel True, but OP says the app does not crash when he presses the GC button on android studio, which I imagine is making a call to `System.gc()`, hence my suggestion.

Comment: I don't think the app is crashing from memory leaks. The symptoms do not sound like a memory issue.